# Iterative process vs a recursive process

Tags: recursion, clojure, tail-recursion, sicp

Reading through [SICP Distilled](http://www.sicpdistilled.com/section/1.2.1/) and trying to wrap my head around iterative vs recursive *processes*.  The example given is:

```
(defn + [a b]
  (if (= a 0) b (inc (+ (dec a) b))))

(defn + [a b]
  (if (= a 0) b (+ (dec a) (inc b))))
```

Which of these is an iterative process (state is maintained entirely by the parameters to an iterative function) and which is a recursive process (state must be preserved "behind-the-scenes" while waiting for the previous function calls to finish.

My *guess* here is that the second is iterative because the arguments can be evaluated *before* the arguments are applied to the function, whereas the former will have to keep successive function calls on the stack waiting for the last `+` operation to finish before it can unwind the stack, running `inc` at each step.

Comment: never knew about the Distilled version, thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's an easy way to tell apart an iterative process from a recursive one, ask yourself: is there anything left to do *after* the recursive call? If the answer is yes, then is a recursive process, that's what's happening here:

```
(inc (+ (dec a) b))
  ^
this is invoked after the recursive call
```

If the answer is no, then it's an iterative process, which is what happens here:

```
(+ (dec a) (inc b))
 ^
the recursive call is the last thing we do
```

In the second case we say that `+` is in tail position, and an interpreter that supports it will optimise it, see: [tail call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call). Clojure can't do tail call optimisation, unless you use [`recur`](https://clojure.org/reference/special_forms#recur).